# Generating elevation polygon coordinates

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have created a raster of New Mexico with a contour line signifying a certain elevation.

What I'm trying to do is have QGIS finish the line around the edges of the state (where applicable) so it creates a polygon. If this is not possible, is this something I can do in GDAL or something?

I'm trying to create overlays for Google maps, so I need to get the coordinates all the way around so that I can make a polygon if that makes any sense.

[image: New Mexico]

Comment: Hi, mybe I haven't understand the question, but  do you try the processing tool "Lines to Polygon" in QGIS?

Comment: I just tried that, and it doesn't seem to generate anything, but that's essentially what I'm going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going to a different solution, and that could be tweaked to make this work: [Create polygon from TIF raster (between 2 elevations)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282269/create-polygon-from-tif-raster-between-2-elevations)